# Upgrade Software from VisualBasic 5 to 8

Tags: vb.net, vb5

I've given a VisualBasic Software, written in VB5. Now the whole thing should run under Windows 7, so it needs to be converted to VB8 or VB9. It seems that most of the API of VB changed a lot in these years, so for me it seems quite impossible to run just a few code upgrades and everything is fine...

The biggest Problem are Forms. There are a lot of Forms in this Software, which are declared inside .frm files and begin always like this:

```
VERSION 5.00
Object = "{F9043C88-F6F2-101A-A3C9-08002B2F49FB}#1.1#0"; "COMDLG32.OCX"
Object = "{6B7E6392-850A-101B-AFC0-4210102A8DA7}#1.2#0"; "COMCTL32.OCX"
Begin VB.MDIForm frmMain 
   BackColor       =   &H00C0FFFF&
   Caption         =   "voice"
   ClientHeight    =   6990
   ClientLeft      =   165
   ClientTop       =   735
   ClientWidth     =   6990
   LinkTopic       =   "MDIForm1"
   StartUpPosition =   3  'Windows-Standard
```

It seems for me that this Stuff was generated with an UI-Layouter, so none self written code is in there.

Is it possible to run this code in VB8/9 or even rewrite it that VB8/9 understands it? I'm currently very pesimistic and think that the whole software needs to rewritten...

Comment: fyi - it's not a good idea to think of recent vb versions in terms of vb8, vb9 (or even vb10 now). The language was completely overhauled after vb6 for .Net, and they went a very different direction with it for some things than in the past. Better now just to think of it as "vb.net", a whole **new** language that is different from vb6 and prior. Old idioms from those language very often will not translate well at all to vb.net. In a nuthshell, you're looking at a complete re-write (as you have already admitted ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse-engineer the VB code to a full functional and technical analysis.

Implement those in VB.NET.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be rewritten. No, passing via pseudocode will probably do more wrong than it will do good.

Comment: i know this would happen... okay i told that to the customer... thanks!